# auto download .dmg files in selenium firefox webdriver

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to download files through selenium firefox webdriver. I was able to configure firefox such that there is no pop up to save the file when downloading for all file formats except .dmg files. I have worked around this but was not able to figure out the solution. Below is my firefox webdriver configuration:

> BroswerProfile.set_preference ( "browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False )
>       BroswerProfile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/x-msdownload,application/x-7z-compressed,application/zip,application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed,application/vnd.ms-artgalry,application/x-msaccess,application/octet-stream,application/x-apple-diskimage,dmg application/octet-stream")
>       BroswerProfile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False);
>       BroswerProfile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False);
>       BroswerProfile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False);
>       BroswerProfile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False);
>       BroswerProfile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", False);
>       #set path to download directory
>       BroswerProfile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
>       BroswerProfile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", downloadpath)

Comment: What is the mime type of the file?

Comment: facing similar issue. tried multiple mime type, x-zlib, x-deflate, x-apple-diskimage but not working. file --mimetype -b <filename> shows mime as applicaition/zlib

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add mime type for that .dmg files. use httpfox add-on in firefox

```
  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/
```

in Type column it will display type of dmg files and add same in set preference.

Thank You,
Murali